# QtCreator (2.8.0), using shared libraries

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, environment-variables

I developing a GUI app with Qt 5.1 and QtCreator 2.8.0 and I'm using a shared library (also compiled with Qt 5.1).
This is what I'm using in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../MyLib
QMAKE_LIBDIR += ../MyLib/build/release
LIBS += -lMyLib
```

Regarding the "Run Configuration" (QtCreator) and under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to "(...)/MyLib/build/release" and it works well. However, on Windows, appending the library path (.dll) to PATH doesn't work. I don't get any compiling nor linking errors but when I run the app it immediately exits. If I put the .dll on the same folder as the executable it runs without any problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say from the information you gave. Surely Windows does find the dll if you put its path into PATH. But maybe your dll uses another dll, which is not in the normal search path?

You might want to try the dependency walker:  http://www.dependencywalker.com/

If your dll is based on Qt it might be that it does not find necessary qt plugins.

Check this out: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#application-dependencies

Qt 4, but Qt 5 is the same in this regard.

Comment: I understand that. But the only .dll it misses is the shared library I built using the same toolchain (Qt5.1) because if I place that same .dll on the folder of the GUI app executable it runs without any problem. I tried to change PATH from within the "Run Settings" of QtCreator as well as using the Windows's System>Environment Variables dialog, same result. Im using Win7 64bit.

Comment: I am guessing a bit here, but I am still thinking your Qt lib does not find its plugins. Just to rule this out, could you add your qt plugins to your PATH variable? Not sure where you find those on Windows. The are in a plugin folder in your Qt installation. They must be findable by your program, too. And I am not 100% sure this is the case when you move just the libs. But as I said: A wild guess. I am not so confident when it comes to Windows/Qt installations.

Comment: Solved! Well, since QtCreator allows me to "temporarily" edit the PATH variable (Im using "Clean Environment" option on the Run Settings) I kept it to a minimum. I just added the paths related to Qt and my shared library and now it works. Thanks for the brainstorming!